# Where do I find the usb serial driver for cosmic?

Tags: usb

Can someone tell me where to find the usbserial driver for 18.10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's located in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko`

You have to use the `uname -r` command to get the release of the kernel you are running, as this may depend on when you last updated your OS, and frequently changes.

You can insert it into the running kernel with `sudo modprobe usbserial`.

Comment: I could've swore I tried `sudo modprobe usbserial`, but that worked. Thank you!

Comment: A good suggestion is to tell *what* you are trying to achieve - in this case usb serial, not some *specific* such as where the module is located... I somewhat anticipated your question, but a different (and valid) answer would be to point to the source code...

Comment: Well, I had already done the research in to what I needed, and I know where the source is. Had you suggested that I wouldn't have accepted it as an answer. However I should have mentioned I wanted the binary. Again, thanks for your help!